# True or False? And Why? Should I decide based on how low the p-value is? Please help.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, chi-squared

If in a Chi-square test the degree of freedom is 2, Test statistic is 5.49, critical value is 3.49. The p-value is computed as 0.032 and confidence level is 95%. The conclusion is that we should reject H0.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter the test, the process is always the same - choose the right test, compute a test statistic, get a p-value, make a decision.

You're testing at the $95\%$ level, so we set $\alpha = 0.05$. The rule is if $p < \alpha$ then we reject the null hypothesis. Otherwise, we fail to reject.

For this experiment we have $p = 0.032$. Now this is certainly smaller than $\alpha$. Hence we reject the null hypothesis.

This goes on no matter what test you do, be it $\chi^2$, ANOVA, $F$-test, Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Anderson-Darling, anything.

Comment: The general principle of rejecting the null hypothesis if the P-value is smaller than the significance level is correct. (+1)  However, I do not believe that the P-value quoted matches the given observed value of the chi-squared statistic. (Values on the graph in my answer looked inconsistent with the value quoted, so I checked the computations.)

Comment: I think you're missing two steps in your first sentence:  Make sure that you have enough power to detect things of interest and make sure you know what size of things you need to detect.  Otherwise the claim would be that it takes no subject matter information to make a decision and I'd argue that subject matter knowledge is always critical to a decision process.  (One could also add an initial item:  Do you need to make a decision or do you just need to estimate some unknown quantity with a measure of precision?)

Comment: @JimB Thank you for that. I tend to ignore power when I explain hypothesis testing to my students during tutoring, only because I never learned it (and I always forget to read about it!).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your question is how to use the critical value or the P-value
to know whether to reject the null hypothesis. The usual terminology for testing
is to say that the *significance level* is 5% (not that the *confidence level*
is 95%, which is used for confidence intervals).

Chi-squared tests are ordinarily right-tailed. That is, large values of
the chi-squared statistic indicate poor agreement of the data with the
null hypothesis. So if the observed value of the chi-squared statistic
is 5.49 and the critical value is 5.99, then you do not reject the null hypothesis
at the 5% level. The critical value cuts 5% of the probability from the
upper tail of the chi-squared distribution (with the relevant degrees
of freedom).

*I think you have the wrong critical value and P-value.* The critical value
for a right-tailed test at the 5% level is 5.99.  The P-value corresponding
to the observed value 5.49 is 0.642. (You can verify the critical value
from a printed table of chi-squared distributions. Typically, some sort
of software is required to find P-values.) The computations below are from R
statistical software in which `qchisq` denote a quantile function and
`pchisq` denotes a cumulative distribution function.

```
qchisq(.95, 2)
## 5.991465
1 - pchisq(5.49, 2)
## 0.0642483
```

The P-value is the probability under the chi-squared density curve to
the right of the observed value 0.064 of the test statistic. If the P-value is smaller than 0.05, one rejects the null hypothesis at the 5% level. So again,
using the P-value criterion, you do not reject the null hypothesis.

The figure below shows the density curve for the distribution
$\mathsf{Chisq}(df = 2).$ The vertical black line shows the observed
value of the test statistic. The vertical broken red line shows the
critical value. The area under the curve to the right of the black line is the P-value 0.064; the area to the right of the critical value 5.99 is 0.05.

[image]